# Creating a matrix to determine all possible combinations of a value, based on different assumptions

Tags: r, matrix, filter

I want to make a matrix which includes all possible combinations of values based on different assumptions for each row.

I succeded in creating the following matrix:

```
total_nr_beds <- 32

nr_of_specs <- 7

bed_combs <- as.matrix(compositions(total_nr_beds, nr_of_specs, include.zero=FALSE))
```

I want to specify a condition for each spec (7 rows)

I tried it with the following code, but unfortunately the code remains running without an endpoint.

```
bed_combs_spec1_5 <- filter(bed_combs, (bed_combs[1,] < 9 & bed_combs[1,] >= 2))

bed_combs<-bed_combs[,(bed_combs[1,]==2 | bed_combs[1,]==3 | bed_combs[1,]==4 | bed_combs[1,]==5 | bed_combs[1,]==6 | bed_combs[1,]==7 | bed_combs[1,]==8)]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which packages includes the function "compositions"? Or is this a function of your own? Please provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

Compositions is a function of the package "partitions".

The easiest way is to transpose the matrix with:

```
t(bed_combs)
```

It now has many more rows than columns which is computationally feasible (in contrast to the non-transposed matrix).

Now you can use:

```
subset(...)
```

To do the rest of the trick.